# TM2 Related lists to show at the Top of the Account Page?

Tags: territory-management

How can I get the Territory and Assigned User related lists to show at the top, or towards the top, of the Account Page?  Users have to scroll down through the entire page to see who is working the account.  Possible??

Answer (score 0):

We can't get any related lists to show at the top. If you however want to achieve this, you can create a inline visualforce page and expose towards the top. Let me know if you need help with the code.